# Google Data studio -Default filter on last month when data is at month level

Tags: looker-studio, datefilter

I have a report with one data source in Google Data Studio. The data is at month level inside the BigQuery table YYYYMM (for example 202001). I have a filter that is set on the year-month dimension which works ok but I would like to add a default value which changes to last month(max(year_month)) available in the table.
Is this possible? I only found the option to hard-code the default selection but this can't be updated dynamically

[as in this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfMRW.png)

[Jaishree's suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8VhS.png)

Comment: Where you want add the default value? In your data as a new column/dimension?

Comment: I have a filter in Data Studio which allows filtering on month level. i would like to have a default value set for the filter so that when a user opens the report he will see last month's data without having to do anything. but still be able to change the reporting month if would like to see data from the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an another field/column as same year-month and always keep the latest year-month value as "latest month" or any name you want. You can use logic like

```
when existing_column = max(year_month) then "latest month" else existing_column
```

Something like this

```
  existing_column   new_column
  022020            latest month
  012020            012020
  122019            122019
  112019            122019
```

You can pass this "latest month" value in the default selection option this option which is just below the dimension. But each time you upload new data you have to update this field like change the table suppose for next month you table should be like

```
  existing_column   new_column
  032020            latest month
  022020            022020
  012020            012020
  122019            122019
  112019            122019
```

You can make auto update by scheduling queries as well in big query from where you are loading data to Google data studio.

Comment: Hello Jaishree. thank you for taking the time. i created a column in bigquery which only holds the default value i want shown but when i add the column name to the "default selection" it is interpreted as the exact column name, not the value. i will insert a print screen in my initial comment. i created column "last_month"

Comment: You have give the value in default selection not the column name.

Comment: I have added some example as well which will give you more clear picture about the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by setting the *Date Range* (at the chart, report level, [Date Range Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291067), etc) to *Last Month*.

First, a *YYYYMMDD* `Date` field needs to be created at the *Data Source*. This can be done using the [`CONCAT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583443) function to add a Day (the 15th is used in the formula) and then using the [`TODATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300) function (although in this case the `TODATE` function is not required, however, adding it as best practice):

```
TODATE(CONCAT(Date, "15"), "%Y%m%d", "%Y%m%d" )
```

Adding a link to post on the Google Forums ([Nimantha; 10 Feb 2020](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/28243527?hl=en&msgid=28246718)) which also has a GIF to demonstrate the process above as well as adding the *Date* field at the *Report Level*.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time Nimantha. i saw your very detailed explanation in the older post but i would like to achieve a slightly different behavior. as i understand with the above solution, if the user would like to see november data he will have to select in the date range 1st of  november-30 november.  i would really like to avoid this because it creates the impression of having daily data which i do not. i have already aggregated month data so i would like for him to be able to select at month level.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a new field where rows that belong to the current year-month are labeled as 'Current Month' while the others could use your preferred formatting (I'm using `"%Y%m - %B %Y"` as it allows me to sort report dates in a drop down list).

To do so, you need your date column and `CURRENT_DATE()` in the same format with the help of `FORMAT_DATETIME()`. Then, you can use `CASE WHEN` logic as follows:

```
CASE 
WHEN FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y%m", MyDateColumn) != FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y%m", CURRENT_DATE()) 
THEN FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y%m - %B %Y", MyDateColumn)
ELSE 'Current Month'
END
```

Finally, you could use a drop down list control with the new field and use 'Current Month' as the default selection. The main advantage is that the code above will be evaluated every time data is refreshed so no extra automations needed.

Hope it works for you.